# How to use a dynamic var in ActionLink to call a different controller's action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**Part of ControllerA:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "ToolScope Testing";

        var Baselines = from b in db.Baselines
                            orderby b.Name
                            select b;
        ViewBag.Baselines = Baselines;

        return View();
    }
```

**Part of View for ControllerA**

```
@foreach (var item in @ViewBag.Baselines) 
    { 
        <tr>
            <li> @Html.ActionLink( item.Name, "Details", "BaseLine",new { id = item.BaselineID }, null) </li>
        </tr>
    }
```

The item.Name is causing problem, however, it works if I use something like

```
    <li> @Html.ActionLink( "SomeName", "Details", "BaseLine",new { id = item.BaselineID }, null) </li>
```

What should I do to have the dynamic names, i.e., the first ActionLink?

P.S.: I am new to MVC

Comment: In which way, exactly, does it cause a problem? What error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

I see you are new to MVC. Good news, you've already gotten the V(iew) and the C(ontroller). Now it's time to master the M(odel). In your example, you are using the ViewBag to transport knowledge from the Controller to your View. This is a typical responsibility of the Model. So you need to create a new class in your Models directory. It will probably look something like this:

```
public class MyFirstModel
{
    public IEnumerable<MyCustomType> Baselines { get; set; }

    public MyFirstModel() { }
}
```

Edit your Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "ToolScope Testing";

    var baselines = from b in db.Baselines
                        orderby b.Name
                        select b;

    var model = new MyFirstModel
    {
        Baselines = baselines
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

Then, add this to the top of your View:

```
@model MvcApplication.Models.MyFirstModel
```

Now you can use this code in your view instead:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.BaseLines) 
{ 
    <tr>
        <li> @Html.ActionLink( item.Name, "Details", "BaseLine",new { id = item.BaselineID }, null) </li>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Martin, thanks a lot for your suggestion. I will try this out, but what was the problem with my earlier approach? Shouldn't it work?

Comment: Well yea, it could work like that since ViewBag is a dynamic object that can contain anything. However, using dynamic objects instead of types means you lose a lot of the benefits of a strong-typed language like C#. For instance, typo's like ViewBag.BaesLines will not be noticed until runtime while with a normal type you'd get an error on compile-time. Besides, replacing the ViewBag with a real model isn't a lot of work :)